# Using Cython correctly in sample code with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, cython

I was wondering if I'm missing something when using Cython with Numpy because I haven't seen much of an improvement. I wrote this code as an example.

Naive version:

```
import numpy as np
from skimage.util import view_as_windows

it = 16
arr = np.arange(1000*1000, dtype=np.float64).reshape(1000,1000)
windows = view_as_windows(arr, (it, it), it)
container = np.zeros((windows.shape[0], windows.shape[1]))
def test(windows):
    for i in range(windows.shape[0]):
        for j in range(windows.shape[1]):
            container[i,j] = np.mean(windows[i,j])
    return container

%%timeit 

test(windows)
1 loops, best of 3: 131 ms per loop
```

Cythonized version:

```
%%cython --annotate

import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
from skimage.util import view_as_windows
import cython
cdef int step = 16

arr = np.arange(1000*1000, dtype=np.float64).reshape(1000,1000)
windows = view_as_windows(arr, (step, step), step)

@cython.boundscheck(False)
def cython_test(np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=4]  windows):
    cdef np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=2] container = np.zeros((windows.shape[0], windows.shape[1]),dtype=np.float64)
    cdef int i, j
    I = windows.shape[0]
    J = windows.shape[1]
    for i in range(I):
        for j in range(J):
            container[i,j] = np.mean(windows[i,j])
    return container


%timeit cython_test(windows)
10 loops, best of 3: 126 ms per loop
```

As you can see, there is a very modest improvement, so maybe I'm doing something wrong. By the way, the annotation that Cython produces the following:

[image]

As you can see, the numpy lines have a yellow background even after including the efficient indexing syntax `np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=2]`. Why?

By the way, in my view the ideal outcome is being able to use most numpy functions but still get some reasonable improvement after taking advantage of efficient indexing syntax or maybe memory views as in HYRY's answer.

**UPDATE**

It seems I'm not doing anything wrong in the code I posted above and that the yellow background in some lines is normal, so I was left wondering the following: In which situations I can get a benefit from typing `cdef np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=2]` in front of numpy arrays? I suppose there are specific instances where this is helpful, otherwise there wouldn't be much purpose in doing it.

Comment: I'm declaring each `np.float64_t` instead. Is not the same?

Comment: Already did. There are some fluctuations but I still get around 121-126ms.

Comment: You probably have too much Python overhead.  Cython use is illustrated at the end of this numpy iteration page: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.nditer.html.  For a start i'd try removing the `np.mean` call (do it direct).

Comment: That might be the reason. The problem is that for more complicated code with a lot of indexing and slicing, I still don't have a big improvement. That is why I thought I was making a mistake.

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks. That is a somewhat obscure example. I'm not sure I understand the general idea other than `np.nditer` can be useful to expose the inner loop to Cython.

Comment: Regardless of how you do the iteration, you want to avoid calling `numpy` functions and methods at each step.   `A[i]` is `A.__getitem__(i,...)`.

Comment: @hpaulj So, there is not an improvement if I add type information via `np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=2]`?

Comment: The 'related' sidebar has at least 5 other `numpy v cython speed` threads.

Comment: @hpaulj I haven't seen anything resembling the solution I had in mind. Most of the time, the answer is either using exclusively numpy (assuming the functions are optimized) or not using numpy at all.

Answer (score 3):

You need to implement the `mean()` function yourself to speedup the code, this is because the overhead of calling a numpy function is very high.

```
@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
def cython_test(double[:, :, :, :]  windows):
    cdef double[:, ::1] container
    cdef int i, j, k, l
    cdef int n0, n1, n2, n3
    cdef double inv_n
    cdef double s
    n0, n1, n2, n3 = windows.base.shape
    container = np.zeros((n0, n1))
    inv_n = 1.0 / (n2 * n3)
    for i in range(n0):
        for j in range(n1):
            s = 0
            for k in range(n2):
                for l in range(n3):
                    s += windows[i, j, k, l]
            container[i,j] = s * inv_n
    return container.base
```

Here is the `%timeit` results:

- `python_test(windows)`: 63.7 ms
- `cython_test(windows)`: 1.24 ms
- `np.mean(windows, axis=(2, 3))`: 2.66 ms

Comment: does this actually return the same output?

Comment: I checked the results by `np.allclose()`, it's the same.

Comment: what is a MemoryView of 'ndarray' object?

Comment: I modified the code, `return container.base` which returns the numpy array create by `np.zeros()`.

Comment: cool, but what can you do with a `MemoryView of 'ndarray' object`?

Comment: nothing really useful for a memoryview of `ndarray` object in Python, but in Cython, access memoryviews is very fast. Here is the document: http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/memoryviews.html

Comment: @HYRY Thank you for your answer. While it is true that implementing the mean function is producing dramatically different results, that wasn't the purpose of my question. This is only an example in which I chose the mean function for clarity. In general, I'd like to keep most numpy functions I'm using. I tried to use your approach with memory views but keeping np.mean and I get 165ms, so I suppose all the benefits are due to re-implementing the mean. I also noticed that the yellow lines are shown in `%%cython --annotate`, so maybe I'm not doing anything wrong with my initial approach.